# Modify "on the fly" the portal column content tag's class

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

I need to modify "on the fly" a class name in portal-column-content tag, this is the html code rendered:

```
<div id="portal-column-content" class="cell width-9 position-1:4">
```

I want to replace only "width-9" with "width-12".
Any advice?
Thank's
Vito

Comment: Are you sure you want an XSLT solution? I posted a reply with a complete and easy XSLT solution only for it to be voted down by an anonymous person. In case you really want an XSLT solution I will re-post my answer, however I don't see any meaning in spending time to produce an answer that would be downvoted as inappropriate.

Comment: OK, I undeleted my downvoted answer -- believe many people can still learn from it. Please, feel free to upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for advise, here is some:

1. **Do not use a css class to signify anything concrete, let it signify intent.** 
   The concrete implementation of the intent comes in the css. For instance, do not create a class named `width-9`, rather create one named `portal-column-content`. You can then make `portal-column-content` be `width:9px`, `width:12em` or whatever.
2. **Doing a string-replace like this is not really a thing you would do with xslt.**
   Even though you could. Depending on your setup there are other, better ways.
3. **If you can't/won't follow any of the above advise, try**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">

       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="@class">
           <xsl:attribute name="class">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'width-9')"/>width-12<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'width-9')"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

Comment: Note that the OP is using diazo, which is a transformation tool designed to style the output of existing web applications (in this case Plone), so he quite probably wants option 3.

Comment: like Dimitre Novatchev, I posted an xslt answer and got downvoted. Granted, I don't know diazo nor plone, but I do know xslt. I'll leave my answer, as it provides an example of, basically, string replace on an attribute using xslt. That answer plus the comment that xslt is not the tool if string-replacement is all you need are, imho, valuable contributions in case anyoe stubmles upon this question in the future. If anyone wants to downvote my answer, by all means do so and get some bad karma your way. (insert evil laughter)

Comment: Pity you got downvoted; I suspect that Diazo questions could do without the XSLT tag in most cases, but that's no reason to downvote XSLT-based answers here..

Comment: I very much agree with Martijn. The XSLT solution is a perfectly reasonable one.

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@id='portal-column-content']/@class">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring-before(concat(.,'width-9'), 'width-9')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="'width-12'"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'width-9')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following sample XML document:**

```
<html>
    <div id="a" class="a"/>
    <div id="b" class="b"/>
    <div id="c" class="cell width-9 position-1:4"/>
    <div id="portal-column-content" class="cell width-9 position-1:4"/>
    <div id="d" class="d"/>
    <div id="e" class="cell width-9 position-1:4"/>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (*only* replaced is the `'width-9'` substring of the `class` attribute of any div that has `id` attribute with string value `'portal-column-content'`:

```
<html>
   <div id="a" class="a"></div>
   <div id="b" class="b"></div>
   <div id="c" class="cell width-9 position-1:4"></div>
   <div id="portal-column-content" class="cell width-12 position-1:4"></div>
   <div id="d" class="d"></div>
   <div id="e" class="cell width-9 position-1:4"></div>
</html>
```

**Do note**:

1. *Only* replaced is the `'width-9'` substring of the `class` attribute of any div that has `id` attribute with string value `'portal-column-content'`. Other `div` elements that have a different `id` attribute aren't affected.
2. The transformation correctly works with `class` attributes, whose string value doesn't contain `'width-9'` -- compare with the other answer, whose XSLT solution in such case completely replaces the string value of the `class` attribute with `'width-12'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this with "diazo", the simplest solution is probably to use diazo rules. Just use a replace, before or after rule to copy content children of #portal-column-content to the theme children of a correctly classed #portal-column-content.

Use an "if" expression if it's to be done selectively.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying <replace css:content="#portal-column-content" attributes="class" >
            vitovito
        </replace> with no success :(